# Несколько listview в одной активности

Tags: java, android

Появилась необходимость сделать несколько listview в одной активности, но при попытках сделать этого, появляются проблемы с прокруткой, отображением. Это еще в хорошем случае, а иной раз вообще все работать отказывается. Не могу разобраться как сделать несколько listview в одной активности помогите пожалуйста советом, а если пример еще кинете вообще очень буду благодарен! Помогите мне все это пожалуйста корректно сделать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В виду того, что вы не предложили свои варианты, я предложу свои :) Например, можно сделать такую разметку:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fillViewport="true" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="10dip" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="ANDROID" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
            android:background="#B29090" >
        </ListView>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="IOS" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listView2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
            android:background="#4A9C67" >
        </ListView>
    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

и вот пример активности с такими списками:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private ListView mListView1, mListView2;

    private String [] data1 ={"Hiren", "Pratik", "Dhruv", "Narendra", "Piyush", "Priyank"};
    private String [] data2 ={"Kirit", "Miral", "Bhushan", "Jiten", "Ajay", "Kamlesh"};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mListView1 = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        mListView2 = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView2);

        mListView1.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, data1));
        mListView2.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, data2));

        ListUtils.setDynamicHeight(mListView1);
        ListUtils.setDynamicHeight(mListView2);
    }


    public static class ListUtils {
        public static void setDynamicHeight(ListView mListView) {
            ListAdapter mListAdapter = mListView.getAdapter();
            if (mListAdapter == null) {
                // when adapter is null
                return;
            }
            int height = 0;
            int desiredWidth = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(mListView.getWidth(), MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
            for (int i = 0; i < mListAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
                View listItem = mListAdapter.getView(i, null, mListView);
                listItem.measure(desiredWidth, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
                height += listItem.getMeasuredHeight();
            }
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = mListView.getLayoutParams();
            params.height = height + (mListView.getDividerHeight() * (mListAdapter.getCount() - 1));
            mListView.setLayoutParams(params);
            mListView.requestLayout();
        }
    }
}
```

Разумеется, вы можете использовать свои данные для заполнения, но сама концепция должна быть ясна :) [Вот](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17693578/android-how-to-display-2-listviews-in-one-activity-one-after-the-other) подобный вопрос по данной проблеме. Также Google советует использовать [ExpandableListView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html)

Comment: Спасибо вам огромное! Начинаю понимать в чем суть!

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ отметьте его как принятый нажав на галочку слева от него :)